# how to determine the sum of elements in each row of the matrix given a null space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This question is not homework, class or project. I'm studying math on my own time for fun.

I'm given a following problem

Suppose that nullspace of a matrix `A` is given by
$$N = \alpha\begin{bmatrix} 1\\2\\3\\4\end{bmatrix} + \beta \begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\\1\\1\\ \end{bmatrix} + \gamma \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\0 \\2 \\0\end{bmatrix}$$

What is the sum of entries in each row?

I guessed it to be 0, since the I'm reading about nullspaces but I can't explain. How can I explain it?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

To find the sum of entries in each row of $A$, compute $A \cdot \vec{1}$, which is the second vector in your nullspace basis...

**UPDATE**

$\vec{1}$ denotes the vector of all ones. So, in your case,
$$
\vec{1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\\1\\1 \end{bmatrix} \in \mathrm{NullSpace}(A)
$$
and therefore,
$$
A \cdot \vec{1} = A \begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\\1\\1 \end{bmatrix}
                = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}.
$$

However, as noted in the hint, the row-wise sum of all entrees of $A$ is given precisely by $A \cdot \vec{1}$...

Comment: Do you mind explaining what is $$ A \cdot \vec{1} $$ ? I've been out of college for a while now and can't remember what this notation means

Comment: So I figured that $$A \cdot \vec{1}$$ means dot product of matrix $$A$$ and vector $$\vec{1}$$. But how is it relevant to the question?

Comment: @gt6989b you're using bad notation.  You should clarify what $A \cdot \vec 1$ is supposed to mean; are you referring to a matrix product, or a particular dot product between the row and column?

Comment: @flashburn note that since $\vec 1$ is in the nullspace, the matrix product $A\vec 1$ must come out to $\vec 0$.  However, each entry of this product is a dot-product between a row of $A$ and $\vec 1$.

Comment: @flashburn please see the update